# I want to know differences?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

1. Will zoologists **ever** know the evolutionary sequences in the Cambrian explosion?

and

2. Will zoologists know the evolutionary sequences in the Cambrian explosion?

Merriam-webster defines ***ever***

> 2a: at any time
> *more than ever before*

But what is the difference in *meaning* between the two sentences?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right StackExchange site for this question. There are many different Science sites that seem more appropriate: https://stackexchange.com/sites#science-questions

Comment: "Will they ever know?" implies "Is it even possible for this information to be known?" "Will they know...?" leads the reader to expect "...when [something else has happened]" - that some further research or discovery will reveal the information.

Comment: In the cited context, future tense ***will*** forces the interpretation ***ever** = at any time **in the future***. But in a structurally similar context, ***Did** you [ever] hit your wife?*, future tense ***did*** forces the interpretation ***ever** = at any time **in the past***. In both cases, optional ***ever*** simply provides more "emphasis" - it doesn't really change the "meaning" much, if at all.